# Slick slider autoplay from first slider in autoplay loop

Tags: jquery, slick.js

The Slick slider is set to autoplay. At the time of play, the slides comes from left to right or first to last. When the slider is reached at the last slide, it starts autoplaying from the last slide to first slide in backward direction.

I want the slider to play from the first slide instead of last when the slider is reached at the last slide.

Initially when the infinite scroll was 'true', everything was working fine.
But due the requirement, I had to set the infinite scroll to 'false'. The above problem occurred when the infinite scroll set to 'false'.

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rickharrison1504/mhtrbhfx/).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.slider-1').slick({
    dots: true,
    infinite: false,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 1000,
    pauseOnFocus: false,
    pauseOnHover: false,
    pauseOnDotsHover: false,
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 3,
  });

  $('.slider-2').slick({
    dots: true,
    infinite: false,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 1000,
    pauseOnFocus: false,
    pauseOnHover: false,
    pauseOnDotsHover: false,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    fade: true,
    cssEase: 'linear'
  });

});
```

```html
<link href="https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/slick/slick-theme.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/slick/slick.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/css/prism.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/slick/slick.js"></script>

<section id="features" class="blue">
<div class="content">
  <div class="slider slider-1">
    <div><h3>1</h3></div>
    <div><h3>2</h3></div>
    <div><h3>3</h3></div>
    <div><h3>4</h3></div>
    <div><h3>5</h3></div>
    <div><h3>6</h3></div>
    <div><h3>7</h3></div>
    <div><h3>8</h3></div>
  </div>

  <div class="slider slider-2">
    <div><h3>1</h3></div>
    <div><h3>2</h3></div>
    <div><h3>3</h3></div>
    <div><h3>4</h3></div>
    <div><h3>5</h3></div>
    <div><h3>6</h3></div>
    <div><h3>7</h3></div>
    <div><h3>8</h3></div>
  </div>
</div>
</section>
```

If anyone have a solution/suggestion, please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is the Fiddle?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rickharrison1504/mhtrbhfx/

Answer (score 3):

Try this code:

```
$('.slider-2').slick({
        dots: true,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 1000,
        pauseOnFocus: false,
        pauseOnHover: false,
        pauseOnDotsHover: false,
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        fade: true,
        cssEase: 'linear'
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @BilasSarker.

I want infinite scroll to be 'false'.

Comment: Is there any reason why do you want infinite scroll to be 'false'? Should I make it initially false then after it will true?

Comment: I set infinite scroll to false because I want to show only right navigation arrow on the first slide and only left navigation arrow on the last slide.
In order to do so, I have to set the infinite scroll to 'false'.

Is there any solution to achieve the above goal (navigation arrow) without setting the infinite scroll to 'false'?

Comment: For sure do you want like this: https://jsfiddle.net/simeydotme/qa3muqrk/

Comment: Thanks for your effort. 

But the slider is neither auto playing nor having infinite scroll set to false.

Comment: Thanks man, you helped me a lot. The prop cssEase was i needed!

Answer (score 1):

For me its working by following code using with beforeChange event.

```
 $('.partner-crousal').slick({


        infinite: true,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 0,
        cssEase: 'linear',
        variableWidth: true,
        draggable: false,

        centerPadding: '10px',
        arrows: true,
        pauseOnHover: true,
        pauseOnFocus: true,

    }).on("beforeChange", function(e, slick) {
        var width = $('.partner-crousal .slick-current').outerWidth();
        var speed = (width * 3000) / 200;
        $('.partner-crousal').slick("setOption", "speed", speed);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been having this issue for quite a while updating infinite value `infinite: true,` solved my problem.

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.slider-1').slick({
    dots: true,
    infinite: 0,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 1000,
    pauseOnFocus: false,
    pauseOnHover: false,
    pauseOnDotsHover: false,
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 3,
  });

  $('.slider-2').slick({
    dots: true,
    infinite: 0,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 1000,
    pauseOnFocus: false,
    pauseOnHover: false,
    pauseOnDotsHover: false,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    fade: true,
    cssEase: 'linear'
  });

});
```